# Incorrect SpringBoot property file loaded in JUnit5 test with @ActivateProfiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, junit5

I try to test a configuration file with a different profile using Spring configuration file name pattern.

Here is the structure of the Spring project:

```
src/main
    java/foo/bar
        config
            RestClientConfig.java
            ApiProperties.java
    resources
        application.yml
        application-local.yml
```

**application.yml**

```
api:
  authentication-hash: fds456f4ds6f
  rest-api-uri: https://example.org/api
```

**application-local.yml**

```
api:
  authentication-hash: xxxxxxxxx
  rest-api-uri: https://localhost:8081/api
```

**ApiProperties.java**

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "boond")
@Data
public class BoondProperties {

    @ToString.Exclude // confidentiel
    private String authenticationHash;
    private URI restApiUri;

}
```

Rest template Configuration

```java
@Configuration
public class RestClientConfig {

    private final ApiProperties apiProperties;

    public RestClientConfig(apiProperties apiProperties) {
        this.apiProperties = apiProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {

        builder.defaultHeader("Authorization", "Basic " +
                apiProperties.getAuthenticationHash());
        builder.uriTemplateHandler(
                new DefaultUriBuilderFactory(apiProperties.getRestApiUri().toString()));
        return builder.build();
    }

}
```

When I run the following Unit test with Junit5, loads the properties from `application.yml` instead of `application-local.yml`

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("local")
class RestClientConfigTest {
    @Autowired
    RestClientConfig restClientConfig;
    @Autowired
    RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

    @Test
    void rest_client_should_be_able_to_contact_api() {
        RestTemplate apiRestTemplate = restClientConfig.restTemplate(restTemplateBuilder);
        ResponseEntity<String> dictionary = apiRestTemplate.getForEntity("/api/dictionary", String.class);
        assertEquals("OK", dictionary);
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to place your code somewhere in git ? because it works for me and i don't how to debug in your code base

Comment: Sure, I'll push it as soon as I get to the office.

Comment: You were right. It is working fine. I just copy pasted my default application.yml to application-local.yml without modifying it . My question is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment) yaml configuration specific to a profile is done differently. The convention followed here is for `.properties` files.

Please refer the shared documentation

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I figured that application{-profile}.yml pattern does actually work too. My problem was elsewhere.